# WooCommerce - Enable this to only allow one of this item to be bought in a single order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I tried to enable this option for a few items in the store, But It doesn’t work.

Option under Inventory tab - Enable this to only allow one of this item to be bought in a single order

[image]

I am still able to add other items in Cart.

Answer (score 0):

PS: *Sold individual means that multiple quantities of that product cannot be purchased in a single order. Other products can be purchased along with it.*

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'remove_all_other_if_individual' );

function remove_all_other_if_individual( $cart_item_data ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $items                       = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $is_sold_individual_incart   = false;
    foreach ( $items as $item => $values ) {
        $_product                    = wc_get_product( $values[ 'data' ]->get_id() );
        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() )
            $is_sold_individual_incart   = TRUE;
    }
    if ( $is_sold_individual_incart )
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return true;
}
```